Next.js Parallel Route and Intercepting Route compiled on dev mode, but not working on production build
We are working on a Next.js 14 project with the following routes:
Our App router
app/[lang]/(frontend)/...
app/[lang]/(admin)/admin/...
app/[lang]/(auth)/auth/...

app/[lang]/layout.tsx contains:
<html>
    <head />
    {children}
</html>

app/[lang]/(frontend)/layout.tsx contains:
<body class="frontend">
    {children}
</body>

app/[lang]/(frontend)/layout.tsx contains:
<body class="admin">
    {children}
</body>

Here are the HTML and Body tag mapping according to the routes:
app/[lang]/layout.tsx             <--- html, head
app/[lang]/(frontend)/layout.tsx  <--- body.frontend
app/[lang]/(admin)/layout.tsx     <--- body.admin

With this base we're trying to implement a modal/drawer feature using the intercepted and parallel routes.
The point where we're exercising is:
app/[lang]/(admin)/(admin-pages)/example-intercepted/

The Interception
We're trying to implement drawer/modal for /create route.
app/[lang]/(admin)/(admin-pages)/example-intercepted/layout.tsx:
export interface IProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  slot: React.ReactNode;
}

export default function InterceptedLayout({ children, slot }: any) {
  return (
    <>
      {children}
      {slot}
    </>
  );
}

app/[lang]/(admin)/(admin-pages)/example-intercepted/page.tsx:
import Link from "next/link";
...
return (
    <>
        List Page
        <Link href="http://localhost:3000/en/admin/example-intercepted/create">
            Add New
        </Link>
    </>
);
...

app/[lang]/(admin)/(admin-pages)/example-intercepted/create/page.tsx:
// server-side component
return (
    <ExampleForm /> // <--- client-side component
)

app/[lang]/(admin)/(admin-pages)/example-intercepted/@slot/(.)create/page.tsx:
export default function Page() {
  return <>I am not working</>;
}

✅ With all these in place, the code was successfully compiling on the dev mode:
○ Compiling /[lang]/admin/example-intercepted/(.)create ...
 ✓ Compiled /[lang]/admin/example-intercepted/(.)create in 1782ms

✅ and the drawer is working as well (I skipped the drawer code above intentionally to provide the proof of concept):

✅ The production build was successful too.
❌ But in Production build, clicking the Link prompted an error on the screen:

Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).

with the browser console complaining the following two:

HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Only one element on document allowed.
and
NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.


What have we tried
We tried all the possible options including Moving the body tags into the app/[lang]/layout.tsx file with no luck
